# Computing convolution of two characteristic function over a 1D Cartesian mesh

Tags: numerics, b-spline, convolution

I am trying to compute the convolution of two characteristic functions over a  Cartesian mesh.  First, I define my Cartesian mesh of the interval $[0,1]$ as follows

$$
x_{i} = i \Delta x, i = 0, 1, 2\\
\Delta x = \frac{1}{N},
$$
with $N$ being the number of grid points.  Secondly, we can compute the convolution of two characteristic functions analytically, which gives

$$
f(x) = \mathcal{X}_{(-1/2,1/2)}(x) \star \mathcal{X}_{(-1/2,1/2)}(x) = \begin{cases} 
      0 & x > 1/2\;\text{or}\;x < 1/2 \\
      x + 1 & x \in [-1/2,0] \\
      1-x & x \in [0,1/2]
   \end{cases}
$$

When computing $f(x)$ over a mesh, would I calculate the characteristic function like this?
$$
f(x_{i}) = \mathcal{X}_{(-1/2,1/2)}(x_{i}) \star \mathcal{X}_{(-1/2,1/2)}(x_{i}) = \begin{cases} 
      0 & x_{i} > 1/2\;\text{or}\;x_{i} < 1/2 \\
      x_{i} + 1 & x_{i} \in [-1/2,0] \\
      1-x_{i} & x_{i} \in [0,1/2]
   \end{cases}
$$

As a side note, I know that the convolution of these two functions provide a B-Spline.

Comment: Your formula looks correct -- it is just the evaluation of the previous one at a particular point $x_i$. As a side note, it's not useful to write $f(x)=g(x)\ast h(x)$ because on the right hand side, the $\ast$ is a non-local operation. In other words, it is not an operation that somehow operates at $g$ evaluated at $x$ and $h$ evaluated at $x$. It is better to write it as $f(x)=(g\ast h)(x)$, i.e., you are evaluating the convolution of the two functions at $x$.